# Yii scope condition faild on join

Tags: php, yii

I've added a default scope condition to the Active Record class

```php
public function defaultScope() {
        return array('condition'=>'deleted = 0');
}
```

but its failing on join with this message:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'deleted' in on clause is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, it should declare the alias on the scope function

```php
public function defaultScope() {
        return array('condition'=>$this->getTableAlias(FALSE, FALSE) . '.deleted = 0');
}
```